# @Required Validation messages

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am using Play 1.2.5.

The below validation is working fine but the message I am getting is not customized.

```
public static void welcome(@Required(message="validation.required.em") String txtName,@Required(message="validation.required.em") Integer txtAge){
    ....
    ....
}
```

Below is the messages file:

```
validation.required.em=%s is required
```

I am getting this message:

```
txtName is required
txtAge is required
```

I wan't to use customized name for the `txtName` and `txtAge` like this:

```
Customer Nameis required
Customer Age is required
```

I can't see any parameters which I can pass to this for customizing the names.

Please let me know about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this with changing the annotation to:

`@Required(message="Customer Name is required")` when annotating txtName

and

`@Required(message="Customer Age is required")` when annotating txtAge

Alternatively,

In the messages file you want can add

```
txtName=Customer Name
txtAge=Customer Age
```

and leave everything else you have the same.